# Python mechanize br.open() 503 Error: service unavailable?

Tags: apache, http, mechanize

I am running an apache 2.4 server with PHP 5.6. I have a form called form1.html that sends it's data to another PHP script that prints out the form's data.

I am trying to use Python with mechanize to automatically fill out that form. I need to do all this for automation for work.

So with this code:

```
import mechanize

br=mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
response = br.open("http://127.0.0.1/form1.html")
```

... it then gives this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mechTest.py", line 21, in <module>

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 255, in _mech_open
raise response
mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

I am stuck on this issue, and I need mechanize to work. Is there anyway to fix this, such as fixing the browser header? Thanks.

Comment: Have you been successful accessing that url with your browser or from python with urllib or requests?

Comment: Yes it works from my browsers with I.E. and Chrome.

Comment: Try it with requests or urllib2 and/or curl.

Comment: I tried both requests and urllib2, but both return another 503 error with Service Unavailable...

Comment: Also, I noticed that when trying to open the url, it times out. Also, I printed out the response.content and it said 'Network Error' and 'A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"'

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Can you access _any_ url with your python install? Looks like you're running windows, windows firewall or some other AV thing getting in the way?

Comment: Yea I can access www.google.com, www.microsoft.com, and www.yahoo.com. I turned off the Windows Firewall and disabled my anti-virus, still timing out and getting stuck...

Comment: you can try accessing from the command line with powershell like shown here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129060/opening-up-a-port-with-powershell  Powershell also has a built-in curl. Another option is to see if running from python 3 makes any difference. netstat can show you local open tcp ports.

Comment: I found out that my script works on another computer. The current pc has trouble connecting to network shares too.