# How can I call a script powershell on-premises from azure?

Tags: azure, powershell, cloud

I need to call a script Powershell on-premises from Azure. I'm looking on internet but I haven't gotten nothing information.

The script content is not important, I just want to call the script from Azure. My problem is I don't know if I can call a script on-premises from Azure. In the case that yes, what resource need to do that?

Can I use Logic App, Azure Function, or other from Azure?

Comment: Your question is quite confusing. Are you trying to call a script "powershell"? If you could update your question to be clearer and include what you have tried so far along with the specific issues you are getting, it would really help :)

Comment: Do you mean remotely via a command line? If so, have a look at WinRM for using the windows inbuilt remote session and/or PoshSSH if you want to call a script via an SSH session.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, but you might want to look at [Hybrid Runbook Workers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker), which are systems outside of Azure that have an agent on them that allows you to run standard Azure runbooks (essentially PowerShell scripts) on them.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, You have some offline jobs that have to run on your local computers, but you want to be able to run and manage those jobs from the cloud.So for his there are multiple ways to doing that.

- Azure Event Grid can now f[orward events](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/more-reliable-event-driven-applications-in-azure-with-an-updated-event-grid/) from Azure to a Hybrid Connection which transfers that event to a specific port on a local machine. Theoretically we could have a [PowerShell script monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129060/opening-up-a-port-with-powershell/13129162#13129162) that port and process the incoming event. To me, this seems like the best way to trigger a script on an on premises machine from the cloud.
- Azure Automation [Hybrid Runbooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker) can trigger jobs on premises. However, this service seems to be useful mostly for administrative tasks, not daily processes.
- Logic Apps/Microsoft Flow can create a file in a folder on a [local computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-using-file-connector) using the [On-Premises Data Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install). We could then use this file as a trigger for an on-premises script that is running constantly and watching that folder. However, Logic Apps isn't triggering the script directly but only via a simple file creation event. This approach would also require us to use a single username/password combination in Logic Apps and remember to keep that password up to date.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info, you understood it correctly. Finally I have used Azure Automation Hybrid Runbooks. :D